# Find the virtual IP address of a Shared Web App

Tags: azure

I am trying to connect my custom domain (in my case it's through Godaddy) to my Azure web app.

I have followed all the steps but I am missing the web app IP address to complete the process.

The [tutorial found in Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/) says:

> To create an A record, you need the virtual IP address of your web app. To get the IP address:
>
> 1. In your browser, open the Azure Portal.
> 2. Click the Browse option on the left side of the page.
> 3. Click the Web Apps blade.
> 4. Click the name of your web app.
> 5. In the Essentials page, click All settings.
> 6. Click Custom domains and SSL.
> 7. In the Custom domains and SSL blade, click Bring External Domains". The IP address is located at the bottom of this part.

...everything works well until the last step (#7). I see no "Bring external domains", nor any IP address.

Under "Properties", there is a section OUTBOUND IP ADDRESSES, that contains 4 IPs. None of them seems to redirect to my site (http://educa03.azurewebsites.net/).

How can I find this IP address needed for the A record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At some point it seems that a bug crept in that has made the incoming IP address disappear from that page.

If you are on a plan that supports domain names, then the best way to find your external IP address is to ping it.

```
e:\PS>ping  educa03.azurewebsites.net

Pinging waws-prod-am2-051.cloudapp.net [104.47.137.62] with 32 bytes of data:
```

So in this case your external IP address, that you can put in A records, is `104.47.137.62`

Comment: I thought about that, but I was afraid that ip would not be static, just a dynamic IP assigned to the .azurewebsites.net domain. My logic was: otherwise, anybody with a free plan could also connect the custom domain to the azure website. Are we sure that this one is static?

Comment: MS states that any none free Web app will get a static IP address for its lifetime (or until downgraded to free) and that IP address has got to be the one that is pingable, because that is what the site responds on at educa03 (in your case) There is also a configuration step that would prevent anyone on a free plan from simply pointing a domain there. It is the method I have been using in scripts for a year or so now, and I've never had one change unexpectedly. (if all my sites suddenly go offline I'll take that back!)

Comment: When I try to go to http://104.47.137.62/ the answer is "App not found". Is it normal? The page redirects me to the link I've shared in  my post. I've followed all the steps, the "awverify" etc (and Azure shows it as configured). Anyway, I've set the A record to this IP, but it might not have been yet propagated. I will mark it as answered as soon as educa03.org is directed to the azure website.

Comment: I've just checked your [DNS](http://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=awverify.www.educa03.org%0D%0Aawverify.educa03.org&type=CNAME&ns=resolver&useresolver=8.8.4.4&nameservers=) and they look fine, so it probably just hasn't got to you yet (you've probably got something in cache still) It is working from my end - but that's fine :)

Comment: After your last comment I saw that www.educa03.org was working but not educa03.org ... just checked my godaddy redirections and I was stupid enough to set 2 A records: one for @ and one for www. The www one was overwriting the @. I've just solved that (removing the "www" one, and using a CName from www to @). Thanks a lot for your help, marking it as answered.

Answer (score -1):

Any chance you're using a free tier app?  if so, you need to upgrade to at least "Shared" to map the custom domain.